# ¿Problema con eliminación de datos de base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

estoy trabajando en una panel de administración para mi pagina web, pero tengo un problema, en una sección en la cual el administrador podrá eliminar post, al momento de dar click en borrar me sale el siguiente erro:

> ```
> Warning: mysql_query(): 
>     Access denied for user ''@'10.24.3.46' (using password: NO) 
>     in /customers/4/a/c/ptplanet.org/httpd.www/inzi/admin.php 
> on line 144 
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): 
>     A link to the server could not be established 
>     in /customers/4/a/c/ptplanet.org/httpd.www/inzi/admin.php 
> on line 144
> ```

## Conexion.php:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario","contraseña", "base_datos");
    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
        die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno() 
            . ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
        //echo "Conexión exitossa!";

   //   $link =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
   //   if($link){
   //       mysqli_select_db($link,"academ");
  //    }
  ?>
```

## Admin.php:

```
echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$id&idborrar=2'><img src='images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";

extract($_GET);
if(@$idborrar==2){

    $sqlborrar="DELETE FROM login WHERE id=$id";
    $resborrar=mysql_query($sqlborrar);
    echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ELIMINADO")</script> ';
    echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
}
```

espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: En admin incluyes la conexión?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu archivo de `conexion.php`, estas haciendo una conexión a la base de datos con **MySQLi**, mientras que en `admin.php` haces uso de **MySQL** para realizar la consulta a la base de datos.

Cambia en tu archivo admin.php por MySQLi y eso debería solventar el problema que tienes.

```
echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$id&idborrar=2'><img src='images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";

extract($_GET);
if(@$idborrar==2){

    $sqlborrar="DELETE FROM login WHERE id=$id";
    $resborrar=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlborrar);
    echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ELIMINADO")</script> ';
    echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Hola, e cambiado mysql por mysqli, pero ahora me sale este error `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`  he agregado la variable $mysqli que es la de la conexion pero me sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: @OrlandoVC Eso sucede por que mysqli_query necesita que le des dos parametros como minimo y tu solamente le has asignado uno.
Tienes la consulta pero te hace falta la conexión. mysqli_query(conexion, query) , de esta forma puede conectarse.
Deberias de poner mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlborrar) , de acuerdo a tus archivos. Para más información por favor lee la documentación en https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: @OrlandoVC He modificado el código de arriba. Si te ha servido, por favor marcala como correcta para que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema puedan encontrar la solución más rápido. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas mezclando partes de tu código, en tu conexión usas `MySQLi Object-Oriented`, y en tu sentencia usas `MysQL*`, si quieres obtener un mayor seguridad te aconsejo utilizar [sentencias preparada](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).

> **ADVERTENCIA:** [MySQL*](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

**conexion.php** (Estilo por procedimientos).

```
<?php
$conexion = @mysqli_connect('servidor', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'basedatos');

if (!$conexion) {
    die('Error de conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Ahora para crear tu sentencia `MySQLi` podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

**admin.php**

```
extract($_GET);
if(@$idborrar==2){

    //Requeremos conexión.
    require_once('conexion.php');

    //Sentencia.
    $sqlborrar = mysqli_query($conexion,"DELETE FROM login WHERE id = $id");

    //Comprobamos que se ejecuto correctamente.
    if(!$sqlborrar) { #falso.
       printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
    } else { #verdadero.
       echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ELIMINADO")</script> ';
       echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
    } 
    /* Cierra la conexión */
    mysqli_close($conexion);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Para el primer error:

ocurre porque no tienes el privilegio para borrar archivos de ese servidor

```
Access denied for user ''@'10.24.3.46' (using password: NO) 
for user ''@'10.24.3.46'
```

Dice que no usa contraseña, por eso verifica el @ y los datos para conectarte

No lleva algun usuario?

Recuerda que: `'usuario','contraseña','host'`

> Para el segundo error:

A) Si no tienes permiso para conectar al servidor la conexion no funcionara, que es el error del LINK

B) En el 2do caso, no tienes incluida la conexion en tu archivo admin.php

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error esta en que en la conexión usas `mysqli_connect()`, pero para hacer la operación usas `mysql_query($sqlborrar);`.

cambia `mysql_query($sqlborrar);` por `mysqli_query($sqlborrar);` Nota que la diferencia esta en la i del final de mysql por si no es muy notoria